# I am having a problem with my code saying the "unsupported image format" and I don't understand why this is the case?

Tags: python, platform

**Support file**

```
import pygame
from os import walk

def import_folder(path):
    surface_list = []

for folder_name, sub_folders, img_files in walk(path):
    for image_name in img_files:
        full_path = path + '/' + image_name
        image_surf = pygame.image.load(full_path)
        surface_list.append(image_surf)
return surface_list 

def import_folder_dict(path):
    pass
```

I tried changing the image format to jpeg, which was previously png but that also didn't work out and I'm really confused to why this is happening.

**Below is the error:**

`pygame.error: Unsupported image format`

Comment: Have you tried to e.g. print the path you are tryting to read the image from?

Comment: If the path is relative, try it with an absolute one instead.

Comment: @Gameplay Well I'm the one inputting the path so I have a module:   def imports(self): self.land_tiles = import_folder_dict('../NEA/terrain/floor')

Comment: @MichaelButscher how would I do this?

Comment: On Windows an absolute path starts with drive letter, colon, backslash or  double backslash for network volumes. On most other systems with a `/`. It contains the full path from the root of a/the filesystem down to the desired file or directory.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'm on MAC so it may be slightly different and could you explain it a bit more as I'm very new to python and pygame. I've tried compressing my images and it work for a little while but then after a few tries the error came up again

Comment: @RaphaellaRogan I don't know much about Mac OS so I can't tell you how to determine the absolute path of a file and I don't know if the relative path is really the cause of your problem. I only know the absolute path must start with `/`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher That's alright thank you anyways